# Excel - Weird Match Behavior?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my experience, `MATCH` is well-behaved when the third argument is `0` (i.e. looking for an exact match), but it is producing strange results when using `1` in the third argument.

According to [Microsoft MATCH documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), when the third argument is `1` (or omitted):

> **MATCH** finds the largest value that is less than or equal to
>   ***lookup_value***. The values in the ***lookup_array*** argument must be placed
>   in ascending order, for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE,
>   TRUE.

But look at the below example. The formula in cell `A19` is dragged over to `I19`. I expected that they would either all return `1`, or would return the index of the last `TRUE` cell in the above array (e.g. `17`, then `15`, then `13`, etc.), but neither is the case.

Can someone explain these bizarre results?

[image]

Comment: Technically your lookup_array is not in ascending order though - it's the equivalent of alternating 1s and 0s.

Comment: @BigBen Fair point. I suppose the answer is merely that it is "undefined behavior" if the array is not sorted.

Comment: I imagine that the algorithm `MATCH` uses to find a match doesn't start from the end of the lookup array too - that wouldn't be the most efficient, especially if the array is sorted.

Comment: Taking a second look, it might be using a binary search - that seems to explain the 9,9,9,9,9,5,5,3,1. The interwebs seem to agree - e.g. http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/match-exact-vs-binary.htm

Comment: @BigBen Aha! That explains it. Thanks!